# Background image hidden behind main image

Tags: html, css

I have an app that displays album covers in a carousel. When an album is centered on the carousel it gets a class of sc-selected. I've assigned a play button image as the background on sc-selected, but it is hidden behind the album image and thus invisible. Not sure how to fix this...

You can see it here: http://lifemusic.cc/

```
<li class=​"sc-selected" style=​"-webkit-transform-origin:​ 50% 175px;​ -webkit-transform:​ translate(320px, 0px)​ scale(0.9999999918937683)​ translateZ(0px)​;​ opacity:​ 0.9999999918937683;​ z-index:​ 3;​">​

<img src=​"http:​/​/​userserve-ak.last.fm/​serve/​174s/​92659171.png" class=​"album-cover sc-image">​

</li>
```

CSS:

```
.sc-selected {
    background: url('../images/playButton.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Wait.  Do I have this straight?  Your problem is that your **back** -ground image is in **back**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ::before psuedo element to overlay the play button in separate element without adding any more html.

```
.sc-selected::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('../images/playButton.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.sc-selected {
    background: url('../images/playButton.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 99999999;
}
```